# What is the best way to separate double into two parts "integer & fraction" in java

Tags: java, math, double, fractions

I have tried to separate 5.6 (for example) by the following method:

```
private static double[] method(double d)
{
    int integerPart = 0;
    double fractionPart = 0.0;
    integerPart = (int) d;
    fractionPart = d - integerPart;
    return new double[]{integerPart, fractionPart};
}
```

But what I got is:

```
[0] = 5.0
[1] = 0.5999999999999996
```

Do you have any suggestion about doing this without converting the number to string?

Comment: Updated my answer with another suggestion :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`BigDecimal`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) to do that same calculation. (using doubles has precision problems because of its representation).

- Construct it with `new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(yourDouble))` (this is still going through string, but the parts are not separated via string manipulation)
- use `bd.subtract(new BigDecimal(bd.intValue())` to determine the fraction

Comment: Why not just construct using new BigDecimal(double val) ?

Comment: because : 
@Swati: groovy:000>  new BigDecimal(5.6) - new BigDecimal(5.0)
===> 0.5999999999999996447286321199499070644378662109375 (and that's not the fault of the subtraction, it's introduced when 5.6 is converted to a BigDecimal)

Comment: @Swati: double is base 2, decimal is base 10. The fractional part is because 5.6 decimal cannot be expressed precisely in binary. If you construct the decimal with a double, then the inaccuracy is already introduced.

Comment: should be `String.valueOf`, but +1 for a great idea.

Comment: @Swati - because thus you are not making use of big decimal's precision. It was part of one presentation of Josh Bloch of some API pitfalls. Don't use the double constructor.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another solution based on `BigDecimal` (that does not go through a `String`).

```
private static double[] method(double d) {
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(d);
    return new double[] { bd.intValue(),
                          bd.remainder(BigDecimal.ONE).doubleValue() };
}
```

As you'll note, you still won't get just `0.6` as output for the fractional part. (You can't even store `0.6` in a `double`!) This is due to the fact that the mathematical, real number, 5.6 is actually not represented by a double exactly as 5.6 but as 5.599999...

---

You could also do

```
private static double[] method(double d) {
    BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(d);
    return new double[] { bd.intValue(),
                          bd.remainder(BigDecimal.ONE).doubleValue() };
}
```

which actually does yield `[5.0, 0.6]`.

The `BigDecimal.valueOf` is in most JDK's (internally) implemented through a call to `Double.toString` however. But at least the string-related stuff doesn't clutter *your* code :-)

---

Good follow-up question in comment:

> ***If it is represented as 5.599999999..., then why `Double.toString(5.6)` gives exactly `"5.6"`***

The `Double.toString` method is actually *very sophisticated*. From the [documentation of `Double.toString`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString%28double%29):

> [...]
>
> **How many digits must be printed for the fractional part of m or a? There must be at least one digit to represent the fractional part, and beyond that as many, but only as many, more digits as are needed to uniquely distinguish the argument value from adjacent values of type double.** That is, suppose that x is the exact mathematical value represented by the decimal representation produced by this method for a finite nonzero argument d. Then d must be the double value nearest to x; or if two double values are equally close to x, then d must be one of them and the least significant bit of the significand of d must be 0.
>
> [...]

The code for getting the characters `"5.6"` boils down to `FloatingDecimal.getChars`:

```
private int getChars(char[] result) {
    assert nDigits <= 19 : nDigits; // generous bound on size of nDigits
    int i = 0;
    if (isNegative) { result[0] = '-'; i = 1; }
    if (isExceptional) {
        System.arraycopy(digits, 0, result, i, nDigits);
        i += nDigits;
    } else {
        if (decExponent > 0 && decExponent < 8) {
            // print digits.digits.
            int charLength = Math.min(nDigits, decExponent);
            System.arraycopy(digits, 0, result, i, charLength);
            i += charLength;
            if (charLength < decExponent) {
                charLength = decExponent-charLength;
                System.arraycopy(zero, 0, result, i, charLength);
                i += charLength;
                result[i++] = '.';
                result[i++] = '0';
            } else {
                result[i++] = '.';
                if (charLength < nDigits) {
                    int t = nDigits - charLength;
                    System.arraycopy(digits, charLength, result, i, t);
                    i += t;
                } else {
                    result[i++] = '0';
                }
            }
        } else if (decExponent <=0 && decExponent > -3) {
            result[i++] = '0';
            result[i++] = '.';
            if (decExponent != 0) {
                System.arraycopy(zero, 0, result, i, -decExponent);
                i -= decExponent;
            }
            System.arraycopy(digits, 0, result, i, nDigits);
            i += nDigits;
        } else {
            result[i++] = digits[0];
            result[i++] = '.';
            if (nDigits > 1) {
                System.arraycopy(digits, 1, result, i, nDigits-1);
                i += nDigits-1;
            } else {
                result[i++] = '0';
            }
            result[i++] = 'E';
            int e;
            if (decExponent <= 0) {
                result[i++] = '-';
                e = -decExponent+1;
            } else {
                e = decExponent-1;
            }
            // decExponent has 1, 2, or 3, digits
            if (e <= 9) {
                result[i++] = (char)(e+'0');
            } else if (e <= 99) {
                result[i++] = (char)(e/10 +'0');
                result[i++] = (char)(e%10 + '0');
            } else {
                result[i++] = (char)(e/100+'0');
                e %= 100;
                result[i++] = (char)(e/10+'0');
                result[i++] = (char)(e%10 + '0');
            }
        }
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: If it is represented as `5.599999999...`, then why `System.out.println(Double.toString(5.6));` gives exactly `5.6`

Comment: Now that's an excellent question. The `Double.toString(5.6)` is *really sophisticated*. Have a look at [the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString%28double%29). (Loosely put: It does *not* attempt to print the exact value of the double, but the simplest value that is closer to the represented value than any other value.)

Comment: "" + d is translated to `String.valueOf(d)` which in turn calls `Double.toString(..)` (or perhaps the compiler directly translates to D.toString() )

Comment: Right. I just took the lazy approach ;)

Comment: (Created a [follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063704/how-to-get-shortest-bigdecimal-that-uniquely-determines-a-given-double) for this if anyone is interested.)

Answer (score 1):

To see what is going on, take a look at the binary representations of the numbers:

```
double d = 5.6;
System.err.printf("%016x%n", Double.doubleToLongBits(d));
double[] parts = method(d);
System.err.printf("%016x %016x%n",
                  Double.doubleToLongBits(parts[0]),
                  Double.doubleToLongBits(parts[1]));
```

output:

```
4016666666666666
4014000000000000 3fe3333333333330
```

5.6 is 1.4 * 2<sup>2</sup>, but 0.6 is 1.2 * 2<sup>-1</sup>.  Because it has a lower exponent, normalization causes the mantissa to be shifted three bits to the left.  The fact that the recurring terms (`..66666..`) were originally an approximation of the fraction 7/5 has been forgotten, and the missing bits are replaced with zeros.

Given the original `double` value as input to your method, there is no way to avoid this. To preserve the exact value you would need to use a format that represents the desired value exactly, e.g. [`Fraction`](http://commons.apache.org/math/api-2.2/org/apache/commons/math/fraction/Fraction.html) from Apache commons-math. (For this specific example with `d=5.6` a `BigDecimal` would also be able to represent it exactly, but there are other numbers it cannot represent exactly, e.g. 4/3)

Answer (score 0):

poor-man solution (using String)

```
    static double[] sp(double d) {
        String str = String.format(Locale.US, "%f", d);
        int i = str.indexOf('.');
        return new double[] {
            Double.parseDouble(str.substring(0, i)),
            Double.parseDouble(str.substring(i))
        };
    }
```

(Locale so we really get a decimal **point**)

Answer (score -1):

String doubleAsString = Double.toString(123.456);

String beforeDecimal=doubleAsString.substring(0,doubleAsString.indexOf(".")); //123

String afterDecimal=doubleAsString.substring(doubleAsString.indexOf(".")+1);  //456

Comment: Why do you answer on a 3 years old question? And a good answer needs more explanation.