# How to get "shortest" BigDecimal that uniquely determines a given double

Tags: java, double, bigdecimal

Basically, I'm curious on how to get hold of `new BigDecimal(Double.toString(d))` without going through the process of creating a string.

The [documentation for `Double.toString`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString%28double%29) is quite complex (and interesting). As I understand it, the method does not actually return the string representation of the number actually represented by the given double, but the string representation of the (near by) shortest real number that **uniquely identifies the given double**.

(I don't actually *need* this. If I did, I'd probably go through a string anyway. I'm just curious about this algorithm that finds this "short" real number that uniquely determines the given double value.)

(This is a follow-up question on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063253/what-is-the-best-way-to-separate-double-into-two-parts-integer-fraction-in-ja/6063376#6063376).)

Comment: If you're interested in the algorithm then the source of `Double.toString()` should be able to help, right?

Comment: I'm curious if there is a more "mathematical" approach, (call it base-independent if you like), than going through though the base-10 string representation. See the "predecessor question" for a better context :-)

Comment: @Joachim: note that the source is closed in `sun.misc` package. We can of course decompile.

Comment: @BalusC: I'm pretty sure that there's equivalent code in the OpenJDK, so that would be a possible route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See:
[How to print floating-point numbers accurately](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=989431)
and 
[How to read floating point numbers accurately](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=93557)

implementations: [here](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/~burger/fp/) and [here](http://netlib.bell-labs.com/netlib/fp/)

There is a [new publication](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1806623) on this subject that may be of interest to those looking at providing solutions. It (Grisu2) works without bignums if you are willing to settle for the shortest string in 99.8% of cases, and an accurate but not shortest string in the remaining cases.

Comment: (off-topic) I thought that you're Ron Rivest from your small picture.

Comment: wow, PLDI'10... I seem to have stumbled across a very intricate question.

Comment: @ahmet, that's funny; I haven't seen Ron since he and Gerry Sussman helped me through some introductory EE&CS courses in the 1970s.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are thinking of `BigDecimal.valueOf(double)` which does this.

Comment: This is implemented precisely as `BigDecimal(Double.toString(val))` i.e., it still goes through the process of creating a string. I'm more curious about the algorithm behind.